# Fine control over Joomla URLs

Tags: url, joomla, joomla-extensions

I would like to convert my existing website to Joomla. However, I need finer control over URLs than I seem to be able to control with Joomla. Assuming that Joomla is installed in the base public_html directory of my user, I would like these pages to keep their URLs:

- http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html
- http://dotancohen.com/eng/genealogy.php
- http://dotancohen.com/heb/contact_info.html

I am aware that I could use a 301 redirect via .htaccess however I would prefer to actually configure the canonical URL of the page. Is this possible in Joomla or with an extension?

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I suppose that it would be if it only cost $39. However, it costs $39, claims to be GPL licensed but has no available source code, and [blames the GPL](http://anything-digital.com/customer-service/faqs/what-is-included-in-my-subscription.html) for having no official support despite the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquestionably, the defacto standard extension is At http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134. It's highly configurable, well supported, and ver well rated.

Comment: Thank you. I notice that extension is GPL licensed, but I cannot find the source code. I don't intend to use it without paying, but I do find that a bit dubious. Alas, for $39 they [blame the GPL](http://anything-digital.com/customer-service/faqs/what-is-included-in-my-subscription.html) for providing no support for the product?

Comment: As to it's greatness, that's purely opinion, certainly it was great when the original developer was writing it for 1.5 but our experience has been less than stellar especially the issues it has with non-standard content components e.g. K2, VM etc...

Comment: Fair enough...we had wonderful results on 1.5 and was assuming that would continue with 2.x.  Thx for the heads uo

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla! 2.5 you can use the built-in `Redirect` component to catch old URLs and send them to the right content without fiddling with the `.htaccess`.

You can also create menu's and menu items that will match the old paths then all you need is to place the content of your .html files into suitable articles. Remember you can create a menu (and thus a path to the content) but not display the menu anywhere on the site.

The `genealogy.php` appears to be a separate application so you can approach that by doing two things, first have a `/eng/` directory on your new website with the `genealogy.php` application in it that way it will have the same URL. Then if you want to create a menu item in a Joomla! menu then you can link to it using a menu item of type 'External Link' - you can read [more about the menu types](http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help16%3aMenus_Menu_Item_Manager_Edit) by clicking on the help button in the toolbar.

**[EDIT]**
For external pages if you want to wrap the external application in your template use a menu item type of `Iframe Wrapper` this will place them in the main component area of the template. With a good Joomla! 2.5 template you can use a template style specific (i.e. layout settings) for that page.

Comment: Thank you! The genealogy page does much PHP processing, I am now looking for a way to incorporate PHP code into the Joomla pages as I want that page to use the Joomla theme.

Comment: I don't mind fiddling with .htaccess, but I would like the canonical, or only URL, to stay the same.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that possibility, but I am not going to wrap a section of the page in an Iframe! I appreciate that you show me this workaround, but I would rather learn how to correctly use PHP in Joomla pages. It seems that there exist some extensions to enable this.